# I can't find UVdata from shadernodes

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I made a UV position of a square mesh, which is located at 0〜3 lines in the spread sheet, in geometry nodes.But I can't find it from an input UVdata node in shader nodes.
How can I find it?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you post your shader node tree too ? For the purpose of helping, it would be better if you could switch to english translation before taking your screenshot :) Also note that I don't think GN attributes are supported in Eevee node trees yet so you might have to switch to Cycles

Comment: I changed pictures : )

Comment: I can find a same issue in more simple situtation.I use mesh primitives.It can't show the simple material.

Comment: Try using a "Uv Map" node and choose your custom UV map there, I think the "Texture Coordinate" node takes the default UV Map, named "UV Map" so it may not take your custom one

Comment: I tried it. But it doesn't make any difference.